# RingCentral API: I need the call logs from certain extensions that exceed a call time from the past week

Tags: javascript, node.js, voip, ringcentral, ringcentral-webhooks

I'm currently working with the RingCentral API and I'm trying to retrieve logs from extensions for the past week. I have a good understanding of setting up servers and I'm planning to console log the data for now.

I've looked through the RingCentral API documentation and various SDKs, but I haven't found a clear solution for this specific task. Could someone provide a guide or example code on how to retrieve these logs? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
     const express = require('express');
     const RingCentral = require('@ringcentral/sdk').SDK;

     let app = express();

    let rcsdk = new RingCentral({
    server: "https://platform.ringcentral.com",  // Use RingCentral.server.production for production
    clientId: "[[ID]]",
    clientSecret: "[[SECRET]]"
    });

    let platform = rcsdk.platform();

    console.log('RingCentral SDK initialized.');
    
    async function checkCallLogs() {
    console.log('Checking call logs...');
    try {
        console.log('Logging in...');
        await platform.login({ jwt: '[[token]]' }); // Replace with your JWT token
        console.log('Logged in.');
        console.log('Fetching extension details...');
        let extensionResponse = await platform.get('/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension');
        console.log('Extension details fetched.');

        let extensions = extensionResponse.json().records;
        let extensionId;
        for (let extension of extensions) {
            if (extension.extensionNumber === '144') { 
                extensionId = extension.id;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!extensionId) {
            console.log('Extension not found.');
            return;
        }

       console.log('Fetching call logs...');
       let response = await platform.get(`/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/${extensionId}/call- 
      log`, {
            dateFrom: '2023-07-11T00:00:00Z' // One week ago
        });
        console.log('Call logs fetched.');
            
        let records = response.json().records;
        if (records) {
            console.log(`Checking ${records.length} call records...`);

            records.forEach(record => {
                console.log(`Call record:`, record);
            });
            console.log('Call records checked.');
        } else {
            console.log('No call records found.');
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Error:', e);
    }
    }

    // Check for call logs every minute
    console.log('Starting call log checks every minute...');
    setInterval(checkCallLogs, 20000);
```

```
Checking call logs...
Logging in...
Logged in.
Fetching extension details...
    Extension details fetched.
    Error: TypeError: extensions is not iterable
    at Timeout.checkCallLogs [as _onTimeout] (C:\Users\chris\Desktop\qserv\qserver.js:28:31)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

This is what im experiencing when i run it on my local machine